# Application to rotate PI

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

We wrote a small application for end-users to rotate the screen on the Raspberry PI 4, so they would open the application and click the rotation they need. If I change the orientation manually in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart it works great, so in the /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart I just added a comment "xrandr -o normal" and the only thing our application does is change the normal to left or right, but if we use our application to do this and the PI reboot it comes with black screen and no desktop. What would causes this to happen?

Comment: Please edit in the contents of `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and the output from `stat /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

Comment: @goldilocks I am not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: You obviously have a means of reading the `autostart` file, I am asking that you cut n' paste it exactly as it is, as well as "the output from `stat /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`".  The first word there is `stat`, which is a standard system command used to get some information (such as permissions and ownership) from a file path.  You can run that command in a terminal and cut n' paste the output here.  Without more information, you are going to be waiting forever here forever...